# Prevent csrf in my spring 3.2.8 application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, csrf, csrf-protection

I want Spring Security protect my application from CSRF attacks:
( Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack that forces an end user to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which they're currently authenticated. CSRF attacks specifically target state-changing requests, not theft of data, since the attacker has no way to see the response to the forged request)
so I added this in my pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when I add this piece of code in my `applicationContext.xml` :

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

        <security:http auto-config="true">
            <security:csrf/>     
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"    />
        </security:http> 

        <security:authentication-manager/>
```

and this piece of code on my JSP:

```
<form:form...
   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form:form>
```

But checking the source code of the HTML generated this is the result (?!?)

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

you can use spring seurity tag library for better clarity and ease:
First include tag lib.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

and then inside your  ...

```
<sec:csrfInput/>
```

instead of

```
 <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

and it should work.

Do let me know if I missed something, and Yes

Happy Codings!!!!!!!!!!